# ElasticSearch - completion suggester in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

I've created an index called `businesses`, and each document will have the fields `name`, `industry`, and `city` like so:

```
client.indices.create({
    index: 'businesses',
    body: {
        mappings: {
            _doc: {
                properties: {
                    name: {
                        type: "completion",
                        analyzer: "simple",
                        search_analyzer: "simple"
                    },
                    industry: {
                        type: "completion",
                        analyzer: "simple",
                        search_analyzer: "simple"
                    },
                    city: {
                        type: "text",
                        analyzer: "simple",
                        search_analyzer: "simple"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

I want to create a `completion suggester`, where-by users enter the `name` or `industry` of the business, and it should return results.

I've inserted documents like so:

```
client.index({
    index: 'businesses',
    type: '_doc',
    id: '1',
    body: {
        name: 'Sports Center',
        industry: 'sports',
        city: 'london'
    }
});
```

But I can't figure out how to do a `search`. I've tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
client.search({
    index: 'businesses',
    body: {
        prefix: 'sport',
        completion: {
            field: "name",
            fuzzy: true,
            size: 10
        }
    }
});
```

The above just produces errors. How can I do a proper completion suggestion query?

Comment: Did you figure out the completion suggetion in nodejs?

Comment: Unfortunately not. At some point I'm going to have to try solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're doing two things wrong. First the insertion of documents should be:

```
client.index({
    index: 'businesses',
    type: '_doc',
    id: '1',
    body: {
        name: { input ['Sports Center'] },
        industry: { input ['sports'] },
        city: 'london'
}
});
```

When inserting as completion it should be: "input": [values].

Second thing is the search:

```
     client.search({
     index: 'businesses',
     type: '_doc',
     body: {     
        "suggest": {
            "whicheverNameYouWant": {
                "prefix": "sport",
                "completion": {
                    "field": "name",
                    "fuzzy": {
                         "fuzziness": "auto"
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     }
```

Here you need to search for the suggest type.